# How to add a file as a link in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

In VS 2008 there is a nice feature that I can share a single file between two projects[image]

How can i do the same in Eclipse (Android)

Answer (score 1):

For Java, you can right click on the project and go to `Properties` then into `Java Build Path`. Under the `Source` tab you can click on the `Link Source...` button and then input the location of your common source directory - that will allow you to put all "shared" files in the one spot and link them into the projects you want.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it forces one to add a whole source folder, rather than a singular file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "**Link to the file in the file system**" button as described here: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/08/15/link-to-files-and-folders-in-eclipse/